# WCF BehaviorExtensionElement nested properties in SVCEditor

Tags: c#, wcf, configurationelement

I have created CustomBehaviorExtensionElement and CustomEndpointBehavior for custom Message.

```
public class CustomEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    private X509Certificate2 certificate;
    public X509Certificate2 Certificate { get => certificate; set => certificate = value; }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }
}
public class CustomBehaviorExtensionElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    private ConfigurationPropertyCollection properties;

    [ConfigurationProperty("Certificate")]
    public X509CertificateConfigurationElement Certificate
    {
        get
        {
            return (X509CertificateConfigurationElement)base["Certificate"];
        }
    }
    protected override ConfigurationPropertyCollection Properties
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.properties == null)
            {
                this.properties = new ConfigurationPropertyCollection
                {
                    new ConfigurationProperty("Certificate", typeof(X509CertificateConfigurationElement), null, null, null, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.None),
                };
            }
            return this.properties;
        }
    }

    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get { return typeof(CustomEndpointBehavior); }
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        // Create the  endpoint behavior that will insert the message  
        // inspector into the client runtime  
        return new CustomEndpointBehavior();
    }
}
public class X509CertificateConfigurationElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    private ConfigurationPropertyCollection properties;
    protected override ConfigurationPropertyCollection Properties
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.properties == null)
            {
                this.properties = new ConfigurationPropertyCollection
                {
                    new ConfigurationProperty("findValue", typeof(string), string.Empty, null, new StringValidator(0, 2147483647, null), ConfigurationPropertyOptions.None),
                    new ConfigurationProperty("storeLocation", typeof(StoreLocation), StoreLocation.CurrentUser, null, null, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.None),
                    new ConfigurationProperty("storeName", typeof(StoreName), StoreName.My, null, null, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.None),
                    new ConfigurationProperty("x509FindType", typeof(X509FindType), X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, null, null, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.None)
                };
            }
            return this.properties;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("findValue", DefaultValue = ""), StringValidator(MinLength = 0)]
    public string FindValue
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base["findValue"];
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                value = string.Empty;
            }
            base["findValue"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("storeLocation", DefaultValue = StoreLocation.CurrentUser)]
    public StoreLocation StoreLocation
    {
        get
        {
            return (StoreLocation)base["storeLocation"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["storeLocation"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("storeName", DefaultValue = StoreName.My)]
    public StoreName StoreName
    {
        get
        {
            return (StoreName)base["storeName"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["storeName"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("x509FindType", DefaultValue = X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName)]
    public X509FindType X509FindType
    {
        get
        {
            return (X509FindType)base["x509FindType"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["x509FindType"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

But in SVCEditor I do not see nested properties from class X509CertificateConfigurationElement. SVCEditor show me only Type name, but I expected nested properties findValue, storeLocation, storeName, x509FindType.
[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN1RE.png)
What I do wrong? Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I solve issue with TypeConverter class. I created custom TypeConverter

```
public class X509CertificateConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
                         System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture,
                         object value, Type destType)
    {
        if (destType == typeof(string) && value is X509CertificateConfigurationElement)
        {
            X509CertificateConfigurationElement cert = (X509CertificateConfigurationElement)value;
            return "Certificate";
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destType);
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        if (value is X509CertificateConfigurationElement)
        {
            X509CertificateConfigurationElement cert = (X509CertificateConfigurationElement)value;

            PropertyDescriptorCollection allProps = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(cert);

            PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptor = new PropertyDescriptor[4];
            propertyDescriptor[0] = allProps["FindValue"];
            propertyDescriptor[1] = allProps["StoreLocation"];
            propertyDescriptor[2] = allProps["StoreName"];
            propertyDescriptor[3] = allProps["X509FindType"];

            return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(propertyDescriptor);
        }
        return base.GetProperties(context, value, attributes);
    }
}
```

And use It on ConfigurationElement

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(X509CertificateConverter))]
public class X509CertificateConfigurationElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    private ConfigurationPropertyCollection properties;
    protected override ConfigurationPropertyCollection Properties
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.properties == null)
            {
                this.properties = new ConfigurationPropertyCollection
                {
                    new ConfigurationProperty("findValue", typeof(string), string.Empty, null, new StringValidator(0, 2147483647, null), ConfigurationPropertyOptions.None),
                    new ConfigurationProperty("storeLocation", typeof(StoreLocation), StoreLocation.CurrentUser, null, null, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.None),
                    new ConfigurationProperty("storeName", typeof(StoreName), StoreName.My, null, null, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.None),
                    new ConfigurationProperty("x509FindType", typeof(X509FindType), X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, null, null, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.None)
                };
            }
            return this.properties;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("findValue", DefaultValue = ""), StringValidator(MinLength = 0)]
    public string FindValue
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base["findValue"];
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                value = string.Empty;
            }
            base["findValue"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("storeLocation", DefaultValue = StoreLocation.CurrentUser)]
    public StoreLocation StoreLocation
    {
        get
        {
            return (StoreLocation)base["storeLocation"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["storeLocation"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("storeName", DefaultValue = StoreName.My)]
    public StoreName StoreName
    {
        get
        {
            return (StoreName)base["storeName"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["storeName"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("x509FindType", DefaultValue = X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName)]
    public X509FindType X509FindType
    {
        get
        {
            return (X509FindType)base["x509FindType"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["x509FindType"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my result [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J9qg.png)